# Can't find the old "sync" in new git experience VS 16.8

Tags: visual-studio

Recently I updated my Visual Studio to the latested version available to me (16.8). I used to use the sync functionality when I work in small proyects with only one other developer and normally he made changes and I have changes so we both sync and get all good to go.
In the new VS I can't find that option anywhere.

Was it removed? Or where can I find it?

Sure I can do fetch -> Pull -> Commit -> Push, but it was a little easier in this scenario to do just Commit -> Sync.

Comment: On the "Git Changes" window, you can select "Commit and Sync" or you can select "Commit and Push" and if there are incoming changes, it will prompt you to select an action (where you can select "Pull and Push" in this situation). See [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHrAg3iKoe0&t) by Microsoft for more info. And see [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/announcing-the-release-of-the-git-experience-in-visual-studio/) for more about the changes to git experience in VS16.8.

Comment: Great Thanks, the blog post I had already read, but the video was excellent at I got there clue to where to look :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to 41686d6564 [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64851538/cant-find-the-old-sync-in-new-git-experience-vs-16-8/64853123#comment114658379_64851538). I review the video and found where it's

[image: Here it's in the Git Changes panel]